# Admin account of progress database

Tags: openedge, progress-db

I'm trying to connect via ODBC to a clean install of Progress DB. Any idea what username/password should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try :

-user sysprogress 
-password 123

Answer (score 1):

Out-of-the-box you have two options to access the database with an account that has DBA privileges granted:

1. The credentials of the operating system account under which you've created the database.
2. You can manually create or, if it already exists, modify the special user SYSPROGRESS with the 4GL data administration tool. You cannot change it's password but you can delete and re-create it with a password of your choice if you have the credentials of an account on the 4GL engine that has the privileges to do so.

Both users will have DBA privileges.