# Progress database one time password

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

I am using progress `4gl` and progress database.

I need a one time password procedure for security purposes. 
Do you have any idea.

I need two options. how can I generate random password and how is the process method ?

My progress version is 10.2b on windows platform.

My project is producing financial trasaction. Client and server side according to a specific algorithm (for example, 1 3 minutes) should produce the password. The generated passwords should continue with the same client process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Admin account of progress database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244012/admin-account-of-progress-database)

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/a/13244053/317491

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to know? How to generate a random password or how to do the entire process? Please provide more details including Progress version.

Comment: Along with clarifying your requirement and telling us what version of Progress is being used you should also disclose whether or not this is a purchased commercial application and, if so, which commercial application (and what version of that application) since anything related to security and passwords will probably need to fit into such an application's existing model.

Answer (score 0):

hikmet bey soruyu algılayamadım.nasıl yapacağınıza dair kod yardımı mı istiyorsunuz yoksa mantığı nasıl kurarım mı diyorsunuz.